# Geometric Probability Problem regarding Triangles.

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading the following article and I do not understand how the authors arrived at the integral expression $2\int_{0}^{1/2}(1-x)dx.$ I tried to use the angles to measure arc length but that did not work. I think there is some sort of graphical representation and the integral is the area of a region. But I can't figure that out. Any hints/ideas will be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what the author's model for this was, since a few steps seem to have been skipped. But let's suppose the circle has circumference $1.$
Then the shorter arc distance $x$ from $A$ to $B$ is between $0$ and $\frac12.$ 
The probability of choosing $C$ as the third vertex is $1 - x$,
while the probability of choosing $C'$ is $x.$

To get the overall probability, integrate over all the possible positions of $B$ relative to $A$; as we go counterclockwise from $A$ to the diametrically opposite point, the distance $x$ increases from $0$ to $\frac12,$ giving you $\int_0^{1/2}(1-x)dx$,
and we get the same thing again going clockwise from $A$ to the diametrically opposite point, so now the total is $2\int_0^{1/2}(1-x)dx.$